# I want to check the numbers in the 1st column is equal to 2nd column 1st column should start and End with below format

Tags: awk

I want to check the numbers in the 1st column is equal to 2nd column, eventually 1st column should be starting with `"ABC"` and ending with `"DEF"` but some times it also ends with `"DEFZ#"` numbers between `"ABC"######"DEF"` or `"DEFZ#"` should be matching to 2nd column. can anyone help me here please.

**My input:**

```
ABC12345DEF|12345|23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ1|12345|23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ2|12345|23132331331|
ABC95678DEF|45678|23132331331| 
ABC87887DEF|86187|23132331331|
ABC89043DEF|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ1|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ2|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ3|89043|23132331331|
```

**Output Should be:**

```
ABC12345DEF|12345|23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ1|12345|23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ2|12345|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ1|89043|23132331331|    
ABC89043DEFZ2|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ3|89043|23132331331|
```

I'm trying to use the following one, but it's not working

```
awk -F '|' '"ABC" $2 "DEF" == $1 && "ABC" $2 "DEFZ"+[0-9] == $1 { print }' WHTFile.txt > QC2Valid.txt**
```

Can anyone please help me here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FS="|" '{tmpvar=$1;gsub(/^ABC|DEF(Z[0-9]+)?$/,"",tmpvar)}tmpvar == $2' infile
```

**Input**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat infile
ABC12345DEF|12345|23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ1|12345|23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ2|12345|23132331331|
ABC95678DEF|45678|23132331331|
ABC87887DEF|86187|23132331331|
ABC89043DEF|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ1|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ2|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ3|89043|23132331331|
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -v FS="|" '{tmpvar = $1; gsub(/^ABC|DEF(Z[0-9]+)?$/,"",tmpvar)} tmpvar == $2' infile
ABC12345DEF|12345|23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ1|12345|23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ2|12345|23132331331|
ABC89043DEF|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ1|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ2|89043|23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ3|89043|23132331331|
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -v FS="|" '{                  # call awk set field separator |
                 tmpvar = $1;     # save first field contents in variable tmpvar

                 # substitute first ABC or DEF 
                 # which can be followed by Z and numbers 
                 # from variable with null globally
                 # so that tmpvar will just have numbers which is between abc and def*
                 gsub(/^ABC|DEF(Z[0-9]+)?$/,"",tmpvar)
               } 
               # if tmpvar is equal to second field then
               # print current record/row/line, thats boolean true, print $0
               tmpvar == $2
              ' infile
```

[Online regex](https://regex101.com/r/c7VYsk/2)

- `/^ABC|DEF(Z[0-9]+)?/`  1st Alternative `^ABC` `^` asserts position at start of the string `ABC` matches the characters `ABC` literally (case sensitive)
- 2nd Alternative `DEF(Z[0-9]+)?` `DEF` matches the characters `DEF` literally (case sensitive) 1st Capturing Group `(Z[0-9]+)?` `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `Z` matches the character `Z` literally (case sensitive) Match a single character present in the list below `[0-9]+`
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: Hey Akshay, it working as expected, Thanks a lot, appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, Thank you Akshay